# PHP html simple dom parser returns null

Tags: php, html, parsing, find, simpledom

I'm trying to parse some table data, but that table doesn't have class or fixed number so i'm trying to catch it by using the `next_sibling()` method.

But if I find a standard table it returns null. Did I make a mistake in my code?

```
<table class="prettytable mx-auto rounded text-center">
```

This is that line I want to find.

And I tried both these codes:

```
$html_pokemon->find('table.prettytable.mx-auto.rounded.text-center')
```

```
$html_pokemon->find('table[class=prettytable mx-auto rounded text-center]')
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: print the $html_pokemon and see what you get

Comment: $html_pokemon gets correct data but find makes error

Comment: does the data actually contain the same table with the same classes?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make a [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) request. And after that you can use SimpleDomHtml. You need to be connected with the page for parse and only then you will get the answer of your HtmlDom request. And you forgot about "file_get_html". If you use [this one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) , find out the algorithm of its use.

Comment: of course i already did curl kk that code is just making error

Comment: And as I remember in $html->find(a, b) always claims and index of element. a - selector ; b - index